# disproving $4^n=O(2^n)$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to disprove $4^n=O(2^n)$. What I tried to do: Lets assume that it is true. So there are $c,n_{0}$ so for every $n\geq n_{0}$ we have $4^{n}\leq c\cdot2^{n}$. Then we get:

$$4^{n}\leq c\cdot2^{n}\Leftrightarrow\log_{2}\left(4^{n}\right)\leq\log_{2}\left(c\cdot2^{n}\right)\Leftrightarrow2n\leq\log_{2}(c)+n$$

so $n\leq \log_2(c)$. Is it a contradiction? If not, how should I disprove it?

Comment: Consider $4^n/2^n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you for your comment but I don't see how this helps

Answer (score 1):

The point is any $n>\log_2c$ contradicts $4^n\le c2^n$, so the bound doesn't work for arbitrarily large $n$.

Comment: So at the start of my proof I have to state that: "Lets assume that $n>log_2 c$"? and the proof will be valid?

Comment: @vesii Not really. It's enough to note that $4^n=O(2^n)$ would mean some $c<0$ obtains $4^n\le c2^n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Big oh $a_{n}=O(b_{n})$ can be thought of as, in the case $b_{n}\ne 0$, that the ratio
$$\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$$
is bounded by some constant "$C$" for sufficiently large $n$.

In a more mathematical language
$$a_{n}=O(b_{n}) \iff \exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}\exists C\in \mathbb{R}(|a_{n}|\leq C |b_{n}| \quad \text{for} \ n\geq n_{o}) $$

So , going for a contradiction, it would be enough to show that for any choice of $n_{0}$ and $C$ you can pick a $n\geq n_{0}$ such that 
$$\bigg|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\bigg|>C$$
Now most easily ,in my opinion, is if you can show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\bigg|=\infty$$
as then we can ensure that no C can bound the ratio. (This I presume is what LordSharktheUnknown hinted at)

Answer (score 0):

We get $\lim_{n\to\infty}4^n/2^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n=\infty$.